# JSF 2.0 - change component style

Tags: java, jsf-2, components

I have simple component - CommandButton

```
   <tr:commandButton text="test" styleClass="form-button"
    actionBean="#{testPage}" action="synchAction" 
    partialSubmit="true" id="btnId" />
```

This commandButton uses **styleClass**  form-button.

I have in the backing bean some boolean member which changes it's value after some event trigger.

Is it possible to change my commandButton **StyleClass** according to that boolean ?

I mean , when this boolean become true , the commandButton styleClass will change to some-other-style.

I appreciate any help,

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an el expression and the ternary operator in your `styleClass` attribute:

```html
 <tr:commandButton text="test" 
             styleClass="#{bean.boolVal ? 'form-button' : 'another-style'}"
             actionBean="#{testPage}" action="synchAction" 
             partialSubmit="true" id="btnId" />
```